# Como agregar una función de otra funcion en javascript

Tags: javascript

quiero insertar este codigo

```
registrar_mensajes();
$.ajaxSetup({"cache":false});
setInterval('chat_cargar_mensajes();', 500);
```

en una `funtion actualizar();` pero crearlo con javascript, no se si me explico bien.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no se entiende muy bien pero creo que sería algo así

```
actualizar(){
  registrar_mensajes();
  $.ajaxSetup({"cache":false});
  setInterval('chat_cargar_mensajes();', 500);
}
```

Será así sino Fórmula mejor tu pregunta

Comment: no que la funcion actualizar esta vacia, pero que cuando de click a un botón por ejemplo, se agregue código a esa funcion

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu aporte. Por favor termina el [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla y para responder siempre basate en [answer]